# Text To Columns then Transpose

Tags: excel, vba

I need to clean up a data dump that was exported to Excel.

It is a file with groups and members in the groups from a directory. The problem is all of the members are in one cell, delimited by a semi-colon.

What I think needs to be done is to create a macro that first does text-to-columns to separate the data into columns and then somehow insert enough rows to transpose the columns into rows.

I want this:

```
+---+--------+---------------------+
|   |   A    |          B          |
+---+--------+---------------------+
| 1 | Group1 | Name1; Name2; Name3 |
| 2 | Group2 | Name1               |
| 3 | Group3 | Name1; Name2        |
+---+--------+---------------------+`
```

To look like this:

```
+---+--------+-------+
|   |   A    |   B   |
+---+--------+-------+
| 1 | Group1 | Name1 |
| 2 | Group1 | Name2 |
| 3 | Group1 | Name3 |
| 4 | Group2 | Name1 |
| 5 | Group3 | Name1 |
| 6 | Group3 | Name2 |
+---+--------+-------+
```

These "name" cells can contain from 1 to 500 names.

**Edit:** While my question is similar to the one that was flagged there are differences that require different code. The other question involves parsing data from the first column into new rows and copying down the subsequent columns. My problem is sort of the opposite.

Comment: What have you got so far? Is the delimiter between fields in column b always a semicolon?

Comment: This question gets asked sooooo many times.  (Although usually the delimiter is a comma, or a line feed.)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Excel VBA - Return separated data](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48091323/excel-vba-return-separated-data)

Comment: The title is misleading.  What you can do is a `text-to-columns` on `B` and then **UNPIVOT** the results.  There are many examples of such in this forum.  Try one of them and post back with your code and attempts if you have problems.

Comment: I had to Google UNPIVOT as I had never heard of it. It looks like it's a feature of Office 2016 and above. I should have specified I'm using 2010 and am using a company computer so add-ins aren't usually an option.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is the code that I used to do the job. Basically it cuts out the first name, pastes it in the active cell, inserts a new row and pastes the remaining names and group, offsets by one row, then loops back. I had to add a loop to remove leading spaces from the separated names.

```
    Sub Separate_Names()

    Dim nameStr As String 'Holds the value for the members of the group
    Dim groupStr As String 'Holds the value of the group name
    Dim delimitStr As String 'The character used to seperate names

    Dim cutAtInt As Integer 'Holds the value of where to cut name
    Dim spaceInt As Integer 'Value for first space

    delimitStr = ";" 'The character that the names are delimited by

    Range("B2").Activate 'Activate the first cell to change
    cutAtInt = InStr(nameStr, delimitStr)

    'Loop Begins
    Do Until IsEmpty(ActiveCell.Value)


    nameStr = ActiveCell
    cutAtInt = InStr(nameStr, delimitStr)

    If cutAtInt > 0 Then
        groupStr = ActiveCell.Offset(0, -1).Value
        'Loop to trim leading spaces
        spaceInt = InStr(nameStr, " ")
        Do Until spaceInt <> 1
            nameStr = Right(nameStr, Len(nameStr) - 1)
            spaceInt = InStr(nameStr, " ")
        Loop
        cutAtInt = InStr(nameStr, delimitStr)
        ActiveCell.Value = Left(nameStr, cutAtInt - 1)
        nameStr = Right(nameStr, Len(nameStr) - (cutAtInt + 1))
        ActiveCell.Offset(1, 0).EntireRow.Insert Shift:=xlDown
        ActiveCell.Offset(1, 0).Value = nameStr
        ActiveCell.Offset(1, -1).Value = groupStr
    Else
        spaceInt = InStr(nameStr, " ")
        Do Until spaceInt <> 1
            nameStr = Right(nameStr, Len(nameStr) - 1)
            spaceInt = InStr(nameStr, " ")
        Loop
        ActiveCell.Value = nameStr
    End If

    ActiveCell.Offset(1, 0).Activate

    Loop

    End Sub
```

Let me know if there's any improvements that I can make.

Comment: When I made use of this, it worked, but with an an off-by-one issue. I fixed it by removing the +1 when substringing nameStr just before the new row insertion.

Answer (score 0):

```
Sub Spl()

Dim P1 As Range, T2(), a As Integer
Set P1 = Sheets(1).UsedRange 'Adapt to your data sheet and range
T1 = P1
a = 1

For i = 1 To UBound(T1)
    If i = 1 Then
        ReDim Preserve T2(1 To 3, 1 To a)
        T2(1, a) = T1(i, 1)
        T2(2, a) = T1(i, 2)
        T2(3, a) = T1(i, 3)
        a = a + 1
    Else
        Spl1 = Split(T1(i, 3), ";")
        For j = 0 To UBound(Spl1)
            ReDim Preserve T2(1 To 3, 1 To a)
            T2(1, a) = T1(i, 1)
            T2(2, a) = T1(i, 2)
            T2(3, a) = Trim(Spl1(j))
            a = a + 1
        Next j
    End If
Next i

Sheets(2).Range("A1").Resize(UBound(T2, 2), UBound(T2, 1)) = Application.Transpose(T2) 'Adapt to your destination

End Sub
```

Comment: Thank you for the code but without a description I'm not savvy enough to understand what the code is doing.